# Is Serenity compatible with Junit 5?

Tags: junit5, serenity-bdd

I have been working on a Spring boot project and started testing it using Serenity but I can't seem to use it with Junit 5.Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481559/how-to-use-serenity-with-junit5/53483402#53483402

Comment: @TürkmenMustafaDemirci https://github.com/fabianlinz/serenity-junit5 But over here it shows that Serenity is compatible with Junit 5 hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the day after I posted the question, there was an update that became available which makes Serenity compatible with Junit 5.Just add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.fabianlinz</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-junit5</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To run a JUnit5 test with Serenity BDD, simply add the annotation @net.serenitybdd.junit5.SerenityTest (instead of @org.junit.runner.RunWith(net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.class) for JUnit4)

For more details refer to: https://github.com/fabianlinz/serenity-junit5

Answer (score 1):

Serenity 2.6.0 added beta support for JUnit 5

https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/releases/tag/2.6.0